# .ToString(), (string), or as String. When to use what?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I ran into a bug that was bothering me.  I had JObject that I thought would be fine with

```
obj["role"].ToString()
```

The string was there and everything.  A final resort was to change to a

```
(string)obj["role"]
```

just to see what happens and it works.  My question is how do I know when to use a .ToString() as opposed to a (string) as opposed to an "as String".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If the object is a `string`, or there is an explicit cast operator to `(string)`, then it is okay to say

```
string s = (string)obj["role"];
```

Otherwise, this will give you an `InvalidCastException`.

Note that here you could say

```
string s = obj["role"] as String;
```

which will set `s` to `null` if `obj["role"]` is not an instance of `string`. **Note that for `as`, explicit cast operators are ignored.**

If `obj["role"]` is neither a `string` nor an instance of a class that has an explicit cast operator to `string`, you have to say

```
string s = obj["role"].ToString();
```

But be careful, the latter can throw a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: All objects in .Net inherit from `System.Object` which has a `.ToString()` method - I've yet to find an object which will throw a null reference simply for calling `.ToString()` on it - Before I -1, can you give an example?

Comment: @Basiclife: If `obj["role"]` is `null`, then `obj["role"].ToString()` will throw a `NullReferenceException` because we are trying to dereference a `null` reference.

Comment: I've seen code like `string s = (obj["role"] ?? string.Empty).ToString();` to avoid the `NullReferenceException`.  Couldn't say whether it's good practice or not.

Comment: @Jason - Then it's really an index problem rather than a `.ToString()` problem - but in any case, good answer, +1 :)

Comment: @Basiclife: I mean, that's one way to look at it. But the big thing is that I've encountered a lot of people that have the intuition that `x.ToString()` should return `null` (and in some cases `String.Empty`) if `x` is `null`, not realizing that they are trying to derefence a `null` reference.

Comment: I like the detailed explaination.  THanks!

Answer (score 2):

`(string)` casts the instance to string and it might [throw an exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidcastexception.aspx) at runtime if the object you are trying to cast is not a string. The [`as`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) operator also tries to cast but it doesn't throw an exception if the instance is not a string but returns null. And the [`ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx) method of course comes from System.Object so it will depend on whether tyhe underlying type has overridden it.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't make a difference in your example.  The only scenario where it would make a difference is if there is user-type-conversion (to a `string`) defined on whatever type `obj["role"]` is.  In that case it's possibly that the cast to a `string` changed it to a different object, upon which the `.ToString()` was implemented differently.